# Django Nested URL passing slugs

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm looking to accomplish a URL as so:

```
/group/<group_name>/discussion/<discussion_name>/
```

My implementation is shown below

#### project urls.py

```
url(r'^group/', include('groups.urls')
```

#### group urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<gslug>[\w-]+)/discussion/', include('discussions.urls')),
```

#### discussion urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)',views.discussion_detail, name='discussion_detail'))
```

Unfortunately in my `views.discussion_detail` I do not have access to both gslug and slug. Where have I gone wrong?

#### discussion views.py

```
def discussion_detail(request, gslug, slug):
  pass //logic in here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're passing variables into the view properly with the 'url' template tag like so

```
{% url 'discussion_detail' group.slug discussion.slug %}
```

Let me know if that works :)